# Custom BootstrapConfiguration class - if Consul can't be contacted, provide default configuration

Tags: spring-cloud

I am trying to develop a custom `BootstrapConfiguration` that is similar to `ConsulConfigBootstrapConfiguration` except without the `@ConditionalOnConsulEnabled` annotation.

The idea is that during the boot phase, various config properties (related to logging, etc.) would be retrieved from Consul's K/V store. However, if Consul cannot be contacted, reasonable defaults for the properties would apply and the system would keep running (perhaps something in the health-check could indicate this 'yellow' status).
Ideally a retry-task could continue to try to contact Consul and once it is back up and running, the properties would be refreshed and the system's health becomes 'green'.

I think the new logic should be in the `init()` method of `ConsulPropertySource` but I am having difficulty implementing it there.

Any help would be greatly appreciated,

---

Mike Norman

Comment: What difficulty are you having?

Comment: It appears that init() is now private so I can't override in a subclass - I have to re-implement a lot of behaviour.
Perhaps I will look at the code that reads config properties from Git and try to somehow wire-in the Consul client (instead of a git client)

Comment: add META_INF/spring.factories to provide alternate o.s.consul.config.ConsulConfigBootstrapConfiguration
Turns out the API is additive, not replacement - I would like to have
custom error-handling behaviour if Consul can't be contacted (retry interval, backoff, etc)
The existing ConsulConfigBootstrap always runs after mine and subsequently fails hard

Comment: Set `spring.cloud.consul.config.enabled=false` to turn off `ConsulConfigBootstrapConfiguration`